# Updating state with new array in React using hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-state

I have a state of array in a React functional component like this -

```
const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState<[]>([])
```

I wish to update the entire array at some time (instead of updating some particular element of pushing/deleting some element). Can I simply do `setColumns(newArray)` ? Upon doing so, my React component is going into an infinite loop for some reason. Pls help.

Comment: Yes, that is how you're supposed to use it. Please post more specifics about your failing use case.

Comment: Maybe you're going into an infinite loop beacause your call to the useState is in a useEffect, but as @Derek said, we need more details to help you well.

Comment: You need to share your component code, then only someone will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

So, it was a very silly bug. I was updating the state inside the body of the functional component. As a result, each state update led to a re-render which led to another state update and so on. Solution was to have the state update based on some condition/function/hook. In my case, I added it inside the `useEffect` hook which executes only when one of it's dependencies changes.